In which space does the converge in Donsker’s theorem happen?
This might be a basic question, but in Theorem 19.3 in van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics" it is claimed that for a distribution $F$ and some empirical cumulative distribution $F_n$, we have $\sqrt{n}(F_n-F)$ converges in distribution in the space $D[-\infty,\infty]$ to a tight random element $G_F$, whose marginal distribution are zero-mean normal.
It is claimed on the same page that the $D[-\infty,\infty]$ space is equipped with the uniform norm. But a normal random variable has obviously no finite uniform norm, so it's even not in this normed space. Also, when we talk about converge in distribution, it should mean that the $L_1$ norm with respect to measure $P^{F_n}$ for all continuous functions converge to $L_1$ norm with respect to measure $P^{F}$. So where is this uniform norm used?
Another question: Can Donsker's theorem be given in $L_2(-\infty,\infty)$ space? I can't understand it, since with $L_2$ norm we usually mean that $\int |f|d\mu$ where $\mu$ is lebegues measure. But when we integrate a random variable $G$ we usually use a probability measure $\int GdP$.
Thanks in advance for any hints!

Wouldn't the uniform norm of a normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ be the value of the PDF at $\mu$?  (and, for a generally distributed variable, the sup of the PDF?)

@EricTowers Sorry but may you give some source so that I can learn? I simply understant it as supremun of a normal random variable, which is infinite. Also, I guese $\sqrt{n}(F_n-F)$ would not converge to the PDF of the random variable, so I'm still confused, to what they converge. How about $L_2$ of a random variable?

To be clear, $D[-\infty ,\infty]$ is the Skorohod space (i.e. the space of all cadlag functions, including for example CDFs). Then, the uniform norm is understood as the usual uniform norm on this function space: compare against Glivenko-Cantelli, which tells you that the uniform norm of $F_n - F$ vanishes almost surely (and this is a very strong hint that the uniform norm is what we want, rather than $L^2$).
Elaborating a bit on what $G_F$ is: $G_F: \Omega \to D[-\infty, \infty]$ can be viewed as a random function with realizations in $D[-\infty, \infty]$, and if $G_\lambda$ is a standard Brownian bridge, then we can obtain $G_F$ as $G_\lambda \circ F$; considered as a random variable, for any fixed $x$, $G_F(\cdot, x): \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is normally distributed, which is what is meant by  the marginals being Gaussian in the stated theorem.
In your question, you mention "the uniform norm of a normal distribution" - in this case, we are looking at the uniform norm for paths of $G_F(\omega, \cdot) \in D[-\infty, \infty]$, not on the marginals $G_F(\cdot, x): \Omega \to \mathbb R$, which of course has unbounded image.

Define the empirical distribution function as $$F_n\colon t\mapsto \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{X_i\leqslant t}$$
and let $F\colon t\mapsto F(t)=\mathbb P(X_1\leqslant t)$ the cumulative distribution function. The process $(\sqrt{n}\left(F_n(t)-F(t)\right), t\in\mathbb R)$ has paths in $D[-\infty,\infty]$, which means that for each $\omega$, the map $t\mapsto \sqrt{n}\left(F_n(t)(\omega)-F(t)\right)$ is right-continuous and has left limits.
The claim in Theorem 19.3 in van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics" says that the sequence of $D[-\infty,\infty]$ of random processes $Y_n\colon t\mapsto \sqrt{n}\left(F_n(t)-F(t)\right) $ converges to some process $t\mapsto G_F(t)$
such that for each $t$, the random variable $G_F(t)$ has normal distribution.
